# Зачем тут нужен this

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть функция, которая по нажатию на иконку включает музыку. В `html` в событии `onclick` в функции в качестве параметра прописан `this`? Для чего он там прописан?

```js
let playIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg";
let pauseIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149670.svg";

function togglePlay(elm) {
  var audio = elm.querySelector('audio');
  if (!audio) return;

  audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  elm.querySelector('img').src = audio.paused ? playIcon : pauseIcon;
}

//2 пример без параметра
let playIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg";
let pauseIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149670.svg";

function togglePlay() {
    
  var audio = document.querySelector("audio");
    
  if (!audio) 
    return;
    
  audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  document.getElementById("button").src = audio.paused ? playIcon : pauseIcon;
}
```

```css
#button {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myaudio-player" onclick="togglePlay(this)">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg" id="button">
  <audio>
<source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
</audio>
</div>
```

то есть можете объяснить какую роль он выполняет? Я знаю что это ссылка на объект, но тут как такового объекта нет, поэтому непонятно.

Comment: как видите в функции используется параметр `elem`, который и передается в нее как `this`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych у меня есть пример и без `elem`, тогда как он передается если там нет ничего? я  обновил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: пример в студию )

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych я обновил. посмотрите, там ниже закоментил

Comment: в случаи с параметром тег `audio` мы ищем только в нашем диве, в случаи без параметра ищем `audio` по всему документу, ето и есть вся разница.

Comment: @AsasSas, в эту функцию передается именно **этот** `div`

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych  просто у меня в обоих случаях работает одинаково. поэтому непонятно зачем `this`, если у меня он и так по всему документу ищет, даже если несколько аудизаписей будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю на этом примере Вы сможете понять зачем нужен `this`.

```js
var myFunc = el => {
  console.log(el.textContent);
};
```

```css
div {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myFunc(this)">Click</div>

<div onclick="myFunc(this)">Click 2</div>
```

Comment: здесь у Вас `el` - это параметр функции? то есть при клике `this` ссылается именно на параметр `el`?

Comment: @AsasSas, всё верно.

Comment: последний вопрос, а если бы у меня было несколько аудиозаписей на странице, то такой вызов как у вас сработал бы для каждой?

Comment: @AsasSas, нет, сработал бы на той, на которую кликнули.

Comment: класс! все понятно. Спасибо!

Comment: @AsasSas, не за что, желаю успехов!